# How upload a Pdf file to Server From Retrofit in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, multipart

I am upload a pdf file from retrofit show error response 413 how fix it in Android Kotlin

@Multipart
@POST("customers/issues/schedule-new-appointment")
fun getShedulenewAppointment(@HeaderMap fields1: Map<String, String>, @Part("service_type")servicetype:RequestBody,
@Part("service_id")serviceid:RequestBody,@Part("consultancy_language")consultlanguage:RequestBody,
@Part("advocate_id")advocateid:RequestBody,@Part("mode")mode:RequestBody,@Part("appointment_date")appointmentdate:RequestBody,
@Part("time_slot")timeslot:RequestBody,@Part documentAttached:MultipartBody.Part?,@Part("description")description:RequestBody,
@Part("request_from")requestfrom:RequestBody):Call

```
        val file = getFile(this,filedatauri)
        val serviceType = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), ServiceType.toString())
        val serviceId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), ServiceId.toString())
        val consultancyLanguage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), consultlanguage.toString())
        val advocateId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), consultlanguage.toString())
        val mode = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), consultmode)
        val appointmentDate = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), date)
        //val timeSlot = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), sheduledtime)
        val timeSlot = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "4:30PM-5:30PM")
        val description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), writemessage.toString())
        val requestFrom = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "ANDROID")

        //val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), file)
        val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), file!!)
        val documentAttached = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("document_attached", file.name, requestFile)

        val call  = ApiClient.getApiClient(Constant.Authusername,resources.getString(R.string.authpassword))
            .create(ApiHolder::class.java).getShedulenewAppointment(Constant.HeadersWithAccess(accessToken),serviceType,serviceId,consultancyLanguage,
                advocateId,mode,appointmentDate,timeSlot,documentAttached,description,requestFrom)
        call.enqueue(object:Callback<ShedulenewAppointmentModel>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ShedulenewAppointmentModel>, response: Response<ShedulenewAppointmentModel>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val getData = response.body()
                    val errorcode = getData!!.status
                    if (errorcode == 200) {
                        var requestid = getData.response.request_id
                        val intent = Intent(this@ScheduleAppointmentActivity, IssuePaymentDetails::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ResponseError", "onResponseError: $getData")
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ShedulenewAppointmentModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("ResponseError", "onResponseError: $call")
            }

        })
```